# Section name appearing twice

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Why the section name is showing twice?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\textit{NITK Surathkal}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Electrical Dept.}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{\thepage}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
Inro
\section{Objective}
The \section{Thesis Outline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have more than 1000 line code. Actually I am writing a thesis for my project

Comment: We can't guess, sorry. Try minimizing your code until you get a small example reproducing the issue.

Comment: Alright..Following is the code

Comment: Shraddha people are voting to close your question because you have not given enough information for people to be able to answer it. Personally I think that this is a little premature as you haven't been given much time to supply a MWE. At the moment, however, no one can help you as we don't  know what you are doing.

Comment: @ShraddhaVardikar: Where is the code?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\fancyfoot[L]{\textit{NITK Surathkal}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Electrical Dept.}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction} 
Inro

\section{Objective}
The  
\section{Thesis Outline}

\end{document}

Comment: @ShraddhaVardikar -- you can always edit your own question.  (two people have worked on editing the code from the comment into the question, but it would not have needed to be re-flowed if you had inserted it directly.)

Comment: The `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}{}` is wrong!

Comment: @ShraddhaVardikar: Namaste!

Comment: @Andrew: _"Personally I think that this is a little premature as you haven't been given much time to supply a MWE"_ OP had all the time between the birth of this website, and clicking "submit" on the Ask Question page.

Answer (score 3):

`\sectionmark` is defined in the standard classes (such as `report.cls`) to have **one** argument.

Omitting it, the `\section` code calls `\sectionmark{foo}` this way:

```
\sectionmark%    does nothing if being defined as `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}{}`
foo
```

i.e. the orphaned argument `foo` appears in the input stream, i.e. it is typeset (in most cases, in rare cases it would be another macro that is executed)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}%
% or
%\let\sectionmark\@gobble%
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 

\fancyfoot[L]{\textit{NITK Surathkal}} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Electrical Dept.}} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{\thepage}} 

\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\chapter{Introduction} Intro 
\section{Objective} 
The \section{Thesis Outline} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: apologies for treading on your toes editing the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: No worries

Answer (score 0):

The redefinition of `\sectionmark` is wrong. However, since you seem to be redefining `\sectionmark` and `\chaptermark` just to get rid of headers, there's a much simpler solution: clearing all fields before redefining them.

I added also the code for using the same style also in chapter starting pages (but omitting the top rule).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyfoot[L]{\textit{NITK Surathkal}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Electrical Dept.}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textit{\thepage}}

% add the following if you want a uniform style also
% for the chapter starting pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% no rule at the top
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyfoot[L]{\textit{NITK Surathkal}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\textit{Electrical Dept.}}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textit{\thepage}}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\chapter{Introduction}
Intro

\section{Objective}

\section{Thesis Outline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The h/f addition code to chapter starting pages is much appreciated :)